# Getting error at opening preference screen in Android 2.2 (android.view.InflateException)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, start-activity, inflate-exception

I getting an error in my app with android 2.2. The error is the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dev.luizmoratelli.cowpea.three.m.ui/dev.luizmoratelli.cowpea.three.m.ui.Preferences}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
```

The strange of all is that in my 4.0.4 android device it runs nice.

My xml is the following:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="pref_ip"
        android:title="IP do Servidor"
        android:defaultValue="0.0.0.0" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And the onCreate of my page it's the following:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        Preference prefIP = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(KEY_PREF_IP);
        prefIP.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(validaIPListener);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        prefIP.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_PREF_IP, "0.0.0.0"));
    }
```

--EDIT--

I'm posting the complete LogCat log and below my styles.xml:

```
11-29 22:18:26.940: E/ResourceType(343): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102f0
11-29 22:18:29.210: D/dalvikvm(343): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2953 objects / 267104 bytes in 69ms
11-29 22:18:29.770: E/ResourceType(343): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102f0
11-29 22:18:29.890: D/AndroidRuntime(343): Shutting down VM
11-29 22:18:29.890: W/dalvikvm(343): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dev.luizmoratelli.cowpea.three.m.ui/dev.luizmoratelli.cowpea.three.m.ui.Preferences}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:107)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at dev.luizmoratelli.cowpea.three.m.ui.Preferences.onCreate(Preferences.java:52)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  ... 11 more
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:153)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  ... 22 more
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-mdpi/darkbluegradientc3m.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f020007
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1817)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:319)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:554)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:157)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  ... 26 more
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag shape
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java:144)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXml(ColorStateList.java:127)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1814)
11-29 22:18:29.930: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  ... 29 more

<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="BlueTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/darkbluegradientc3m</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@drawable/darkbluegradientc3m</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/spinner_list_view</item>
        <item name="android:listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/list_selector_c3m</item>
    </style>

    <style name="text_title" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">#E5E6FF</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    </style>

    <style name="text_regular" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">#AADDFF</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="text_dropdownitem" parent="@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem">
        <item name="android:textColor">#AADDFF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/roundedbutton</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="buttonLogin" parent="@style/button">
        <item name="android:layout_height">80dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="buttonMenu" parent="@style/button">
        <item name="android:layout_height">70dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="editText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:ems">10</item>
    </style>

    <style name="spinner" parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerMode">dropdown</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/darkbluegradientroundedc3m</item>
    </style>

        <style name="spinner_list_view" parent="@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:divider">#696969</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

--EDIT2-- The xml from  darkbluegradientec3m.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#FF16163D"
        android:endColor="#FF010105"
        android:type="linear"
        />
</shape>
```

Comment: What shapes are you declaring as drawables in XML? That's the cause according to the logcat ..

Comment: I'm declaring a simple gradiente. Here it is the drawable xml that he's mentioning in logcat:  `<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#FF16163D"
        android:endColor="#FF010105"
        android:type="linear"
        />
</shape>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems problems with the tag *[colorBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#colorBackground)* in your **BlueTheme**, since documentation it takes color-values ​​Like *#abc* or links to them. Possible that different versions of Android parse this tag different. Try to use a simple color-value, not a drawable.

Also your tag *[listChoiceBackgroundIndicator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#listChoiceBackgroundIndicator)* will not work on android with API 11<.

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised that it really worked. How I can put a gradient background in android 2.2? There is a way?

Comment: I'm not sure, but what if you set android:background="@drawable/darkbluegradientc3m" in your theme? Or it can be more useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3560677/1001401