# How to remove colorPrimary as the background of Android PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am using two `SwitchPreferences` inside a `PreferenceCategory` and the `xml` is as follows.

```
<PreferenceCategory 
android:title="Control usage of the PIN" >
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="pin_onmessage_onoff"
        android:summary="For Message"
        android:title="Use for Message" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="pin_onvault_onoff"
        android:summary="For Vault"
        android:title="Use for Vault" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

The background of each `SwitchPreference` is the `colorPrimary` value. My question is how I could remove the background color from the `Preferences`?

Note : Can't attach a screenshot where Image upload redirects to a blank page.

Comment: Create your custom theme for Preferences.

Comment: It did the trick. I was wondering any other methods are there to be applied.

Comment: This old post have some approaches to your problem: [Preference background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551169/change-background-color-of-preference)

Comment: @rain_ Yeah. That's what I did, as Stanojkovic suggested, by using a separate theme. Thanks.